# Order CSS Styles with Transitions and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

if i apply a style to an element and immdiatily afterwards add css transition styles, the transition is applied to the style preceeding. this might not always be the intention.

i found a solution by using settimeout (0), is there any cleaner/more correct approach known ?

http://jsfiddle.net/nicib83/XP9E7/

```
$("div").css("opacity", 1);

$("div").css("-webkit-transition", "all 0.35s");

/* Works
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $("div").css("-webkit-transition", "all 0.35s");
}, 0);
*/
```

best regards

Edit:

i didn't mean how best to set css styling but how to sequentially set styles when the first style should be applied without the second being active at that time but only afterwards, i wan to add transition afterwards. settimeout fixes it, best solution ?

Comment: I would recommend adding css classes, rather than applying the styles directly in css. As for your question, applying the style immediately is the appropriate behavior in a *cascading* style sheet.

Comment: "afterwards"— after what? page load? click?

Comment: i preposition elements, the initial style change should be done without transition, immediately after the initial state is set, the transition property should be added so that any further style changes are applied with that transition, the simple solution could be to just apply the transition right before the later event, my question related more the the fact whether it is possible to set a style and afterwards a transition without the transiton being applied to the previous statement, it seems like the browser needs a break (achieved by settimeout) to do repaint

Comment: Please describe the specific sequence of *behaviors* you want, so we can work from that, rather than focusing on the CSS rules alone. You want to change the opacity without any transition, and then apply the transition property so that it's in effect for all *subsequent* CSS changes?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to pre-define a class that contains both of the properties you want to apply, and add that class programmatically to the element. Both of the properties will be applied together.

```
.myClass {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
}

$("div").addClass("myClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a page from the book of Twitter Bootstrap:

```
fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.15s linear;
    transition:opacity 0.15s linear;
}
.fade.in{
    opacity:1;
}
```

then programatically add the `.in` class when you want it to fade in:

```
$("div").addClass("in");
```

with your original div looking something like:

```
<div class="fade">Box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been running up against this myself and also found the setTimeout solution. After some research the issue is how the browser handles scheduling. The JavaScript runs in its own thread separate from the threads dealing with the UI and the DOM (which is why issues like UI blocking happen).

In cases like this both JavaScript statements run before the document registers the first change and it ends up applying both classes at the same time. setTimeout(fn,0) effectively makes the function asynchronous and shunts the functions to run at the next available opportunity. This allows the UI thread to catch up before the next class is added.