# minimum interval between setting css transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I want to set instantly some css property to some value, and then start transition from this value to different one. **I need to call that several times.** 
When I run for the first time, or I do it step-by-step on the console it works as expected, however when executed in single javascript function it does not work unless I force some delay using setTimeout.

Running on the console line-by-line works, but called all at once doesn't:

```
el.style.transition = ''; // no transition from now
el.style.left = '50px'; // set instantly to 50
el.style.transition = '1s'; // 1s transition from now
el.style.left = '250px'; // animate from 50 to 250
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wsrv0mg/7/) demo.

So, the **question is** - how do I update css transition, to make sure it will work, and/or when I update css transition how do I know if/when it's started to affect other properties I would like to animate?

**Update:**

From my tests, is seems like setting transition property works somehow asynchronously, but I cannot find any way to set callback for its change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution (http://jsfiddle.net/9wsrv0mg/9/).

The trick is to read some DOM property which will force browser js and rendering thread to sync.

So, this will work:

```
el.style.transition = '';
el.style.left='50px';
var tmp = el.offsetLeft; // HERE COMES THE MAGIC - reading this prop forces delay we need
el.style.transition = 'left 1s';
el.style.left='250px';
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the transition to:

`el.style.transition="left 1s linear 1s"`.

You need to use the CSS3 [transition-delay](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp) property, but you can set this in the broader [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property that you used. This allows a few transition options to be set, the fourth of which is the delay time.

> Formal syntax: [ none | < single-transition-property > ] || < time > || < timing-function > || < time

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbLLkd3r/3/).  It appears initially you need a slight delay for the transition not to act on the previous style change.  There is no callback for a style property change so you just need to force the update of the transition element into the next browser event loop.  It's been noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839869/609907) answer too.

```
el.style.transition = 'left 0s linear 0s'; // no transition from now
el.style.left = '50px'; // set instantly to 50
setTimeout(function(){
    el.style.transition = 'left 1s linear 1s'; // 1s transition from now
    el.style.left = '250px'; // set instantly to 50
}, 0);
```

Comment: setting delay to "1s" or "0s" does no t work. I tested on firefox and chrome. Did you try it on jsfiddle?

Comment: thanks for your,effort, but it works only on the first call. Please see updated http://jsfiddle.net/fbLLkd3r/1/ I managed to break again :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62175/discussion-between-richieahb-and-michal-srajer).

Comment: unfortunatelly, setTimeout(, 0) does not always work

Comment: How about setTimeout( ,1) - I can't see that not working.  A browser event will not span a millisecond.